# Mockito: "Checked exception is invalid for this method" when throwing specified checked exception

Tags: java, mockito

There are several questions around this on StackOverflow, but I believe this case to be different. I'm using Java 11 and Mockito 2.11.0.

Here's a minimal JUnit 4 test case demonstrating my problem:

```
@Test
public void shouldAllowMocking() throws Exception {
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);
  when(objectMapper.readValue(anyString(), any(Class.class))).thenThrow(new IOException("the-message"));
}
```

I'm mocking the behaviour of Jackson's ObjectMapper's `readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType)` method - documentation [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) - and the documentation shows that that method can throw an `IOException`. So why does Mockito report that it is invalid for me to mock throwing such an exception?

Interestingly, if I change the behaviour to throw a `JsonParseException`, which can also be thrown by that method, then Mockito doesn't complain.

Comment: What version of jackson-databind are you using? The link points to the 2.7 but is it the same as the one you use in the code?

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's helpful. They've changed the signature and now it doesn't throw that exception any more. I should pay better attention to my documentation versions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version `2.10` Jackson removed the IOException, this is the portion of the code:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T readValue(String content, JavaType valueType)
    throws JsonProcessingException, JsonMappingException
{
    _assertNotNull("content", content);
    try { // since 2.10 remove "impossible" IOException as per [databind#1675]
        return (T) _readMapAndClose(_jsonFactory.createParser(content), valueType);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) { // shouldn't really happen but being declared need to
        throw JsonMappingException.fromUnexpectedIOE(e);
    }
}
```

The link you included in the question points to the jakson-databind 2.7 so I assume you are checking the wrong doc.

Answer (score 1):

This turns out to be because I'd unintentionally updated my `jackson` version as well, and the newer versions (2.11.x) don't throw `IOException` any more.

Comment: Specifically since version `2.10` of Jackson Databind